# Error Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093] PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hola me gustaría que me ayudaran a solventar este error, intento modificar datos de la base de datos, de hecho el formato es simple, aun soy estudiante pero sigo sin encontrar el error, aqui esta el error que me manda cuando intento mandar la informacion:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Egresado\user\edito.php:74 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Egresado\user\edito.php(74): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Egresado\user\edito.php on line 74

Este es el codigo que estoy usando para enviar a la base de datos

```
 require '../profile.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $id = $Person['Id'];
    $telcel = $_POST['telcel'];
    $teljaus = $_POST['teljaus'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $colonia = $_POST['colonia'];
    $cp = $_POST['cp'];
    $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $universidad = $_POST['universidad'];
    $carrera = $_POST['carrera'];
    $teluniv = $_POST['teluniv'];
    $direccionuniv = $_POST['direcuniv'];
    $ciudaduniv = $_POST['ciudaduniv'];
    $estadouniv = $_POST['estadouniv'];
    $nombrework = $_POST['namework'];
    $puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
    $direccionwork = $_POST['direcwork'];
    $telwork = $_POST['telwork'];
    $ciudadwork = $_POST['ciudadwork'];
    $estadowork = $_POST['estadowork'];


    $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE alumno SET 
                                        TelCel = :telcel,
                                        TelHome = :teljaus,
                                        Email = :email,
                                        Calle = :direccion,
                                        Colonia = :colonia,
                                        CP = :cp,
                                        Ciudad = :ciudad,
                                        Estado = :estado,
                                        Universidad = :universidad,
                                        Carrera = :carrera,
                                        TelUniv = teluniv,
                                        DireccionUniv = :direcuniv,
                                        CiudadUniv = :ciudaduniv,
                                        EstadoUniv = :estadouniv,
                                        NameWork = :namework,
                                        Ocupation = :puesto,
                                        DireccionWork = :direcwork,
                                        TelWork = :telwork,
                                        CiudadWork = :ciudadwork,
                                        EstadoWork = :estadowork 
                                        WHERE Id = :Id");

    //print_r($statement);

    $statement->execute(array(
                        ':telcel' => $telcel,
                        ':teljaus' => $teljaus,
                        ':email' => $email,
                        ':direccion' => $direccion,
                        ':colonia' => $colonia,
                        ':cp' => $cp,
                        ':ciudad' => $ciudad,
                        ':estado' => $estado,
                        ':universidad' => $universidad,
                        ':carrera' => $carrera,
                        ':teluniv' => $teluniv,
                        ':direcuniv' => $direccionuniv,
                        ':ciudaduniv' => $ciudaduniv,
                        ':estadouniv' => $estadouniv,
                        ':namework' => $nombrework,
                        ':puesto' => $puesto,
                        ':direcwork' => $direccionwork,
                        ':telwork' => $telwork,
                        ':ciudadwork' => $ciudadwork,
                        ':Id' => $id,
                        ':estadowork' => $estadowork
    ));

    //print_r($statement);

    header ('Location: index.php');
}
```

y por acá esta la vista que estoy usando junto con el formulario

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>COBAEV 32 Coatzintla</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../images/images/logo.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/noscript.css" />
</head>
<body  class="is-preload">
    <div id="page-wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.php">COBAEV 32</a></h1>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Bienvenido <?php echo $Person['Nombres']; ?></a></li>                            
                            <li><a href="../cerrar.php" class="button primary">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>

            <!--Content -->
                <div id="main" class="wrapper style1">
                    <div class="container">
                        <section>
                            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class='formulario' name='edit'>
                                <h2>Información Personal</h2>
                                <div class="row gtr-uniform gtr-50">
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Teléfono celular</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="telcel" value="<?php echo $Person['TelCel']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Teléfono de casa</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="teljaus" value="<?php echo $Person['TelHome']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Correo Electrónico</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $Person['Email']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Calle y número</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $Person['Calle']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Ciudad</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="ciudad" value="<?php echo $Person['Ciudad']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Codigo postal</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="cp" value="<?php echo $Person['CP']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Colonia</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="colonia" value="<?php  echo $Person['Colonia'] ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Estado</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="estado" value="<?php echo $Person['Estado'] ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <h2>Información Escolar</h2>    
                                <div class="row gtr-uniform gtr-50">
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Nombre Universidad</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="universidad" value="<?php echo $Person['Universidad']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Carrera</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="carrera" value="<?php echo $Person['Carrera']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Telefono Univerisdad</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="teluniv" value="<?php echo $Person['TelUniv']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Direccion Universidad</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="direcuniv" value="<?php echo $Person['DireccionUniv']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Ciudad Universidad</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="ciudaduniv" value="<?php echo $Person['CiudadUniv']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Estado Universidad</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="estadouniv" value="<?php echo $Person['EstadoUniv']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <h2>Información Laboral</h2>
                                <div class="row gtr-uniform gtr-50">
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Nombre Trabajo</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="namework" value="<?php echo $Person['NameWork']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Puesto</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="puesto" value="<?php echo $Person['Ocupation']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Direccion del trabajo</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="direcwork" value="<?php echo $Person['DireccionWork']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Telefono Trabajo</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="telwork" value="<?php echo $Person['TelWork']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Ciudad Trabajo</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="ciudadwork" value="<?php echo $Person['CiudadWork']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                                        <h4>Estado Trabajo</h4>
                                        <input type="text" name="estadowork" value="<?php echo $Person['EstadoWork']; ?> ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modificar Datos" class="primary" /></li>
                                        <li><input type="reset" value="Borrar campos" /></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>  
                            </form>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
                <footer id="footer">
                    <ul class="icons">
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands  fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands  fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands  fa-linkedin-in"><span class="label">LinkedIn</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands  fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon brands  fa-github"><span class="label">GitHub</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon solid   fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="copyright">
                        <li>&copy; COBAEV 32 Coatzintla. Todos los derechos reservados <?php echo date("Y"); ?>.</li><li>Diseño: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/akisaiseei/" target="_blank">Akisa Iseei</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>           
    </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el error de forma mas detallada si se puede decir así

```
>Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Egresado\user\edito.php:74
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Egresado\user\edito.php(74): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Egresado\user\edito.php on line 74
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es causado por que el numero de campos en la consulta no son los mismos en el array, ademas de verificar que sea el mismo numero de campos, también verifica que tengan el mismo nombre, y que también estén en el mismo orden.

Inténtalo de esta forma

```
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE alumno SET 
                                        TelCel = :telcel,
                                        TelHome = :teljaus,
                                        Email = :email,
                                        Calle = :direccion,
                                        Colonia = :colonia,
                                        CP = :cp,
                                        Ciudad = :ciudad,
                                        Estado = :estado,
                                        Universidad = :universidad,
                                        Carrera = :carrera,
                                        TelUniv = teluniv,
                                        DireccionUniv = :direccionuniv, // puse el mismo nombre
                                        CiudadUniv = :ciudaduniv,
                                        EstadoUniv = :estadouniv,
                                        NameWork = :namework,
                                        Ocupation = :puesto,
                                        DireccionWork = :direcwork,
                                        TelWork = :telwork,
                                        CiudadWork = :ciudadwork,
                                        EstadoWork = :estadowork 
                                        WHERE Id = :id // cambie de Id a id
                                        ");

    //print_r($statement);

    $statement->execute(array(
                        ':telcel' => $telcel,
                        ':teljaus' => $teljaus,
                        ':email' => $email,
                        ':direccion' => $direccion,
                        ':colonia' => $colonia,
                        ':cp' => $cp,
                        ':ciudad' => $ciudad,
                        ':estado' => $estado,
                        ':universidad' => $universidad,
                        ':carrera' => $carrera,
                        ':teluniv' => $teluniv,
                        ':direcuniv' => $direccionuniv, // que el de aqui
                        ':ciudaduniv' => $ciudaduniv,
                        ':estadouniv' => $estadouniv,
                        ':namework' => $nombrework,
                        ':puesto' => $puesto,
                        ':direcwork' => $direccionwork,
                        ':telwork' => $telwork,
                        ':ciudadwork' => $ciudadwork,
                        ':estadowork' => $estadowork,
                        ':Id' => $id //Puse el id al final como 
    ));

    //print_r($statement);

    header ('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente y no a funcionado :(, ya le he movido varios parametros que he pesado que pueden ser pero no a funcionado

Comment: Puede poner una captura de tu tabla alumno ?

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado!! Me faltaba un ":" cuando estaba preparando la consulta, Muchas gracias como quiera!!

Comment: Aquí faltan los dos puntos: `TelUniv = teluniv,`  y este marcador no coincide con el array que pasas en el `execute`: `DireccionUniv = :direccionuniv,` ... este marcador tampoco coincide: `:Id' => $id`. Cabe aclarar que los  `:marcadores` **de nombre** pueden llamarse como uno quiera, no tienen que llamarse obligatoriamente igual que la columna (aunque generalmente se hace así por claridad), **lo que hay que cuidar es que los pongas igual en la consulta y en el array**...

Comment: ... Puedes usar algo como `:ugly` en la SQL pero en el array tienes que poner `':ugly'=>$valor`. También, en el array los puedes poner en el orden que quieras (aunque siempre se pone en el mismo orden que en la consulta para fines de claridad y revisión), pero si no están en el mismo orden no pasa nada. En el caso de los **marcadores de `:nombre`** PDO asigna los valores según el marcador de `:nombre`. Si fueran marcadores de posición `?` entonces sí hay que respetar el orden sí o sí.